# Create dynamodb table without hash

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to create a table without hash key. But I am getting error
`You must specify a KeySchema list.` How can I create the table without any key?

```
userAccount:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  DeletionPolicy : Retain
  Properties:
    TableName: userAccount
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: userId
        AttributeType: S
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: userId
        KeyType: S
    ProvisionedThroughput:
      ReadCapacityUnits: 1
      WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hashkey` is must for the DynamoDB table. You can't create the table without the hash key.

**Hash Key:-**

Hash key is mandatory.

> The partition key of an item is also known as its hash attribute. The
> term "hash attribute" derives from the DynamoDB usage of an internal
> hash function to evenly distribute data items across partitions, based
> on their partition key values.

**Sort Key:-**

Sort key is optional.

> The sort key of an item is also known as its range attribute. The term
> "range attribute" derives from the way DynamoDB stores items with the
> same partition key physically close together, in sorted order by the
> sort key value.

Answer (score 2):

According to [aws dynamodb doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html), when you create a table, you **must** specify a primary key as it allows to identify each item in the table. DynamoDb supports two types of primary keys:

**1. **Partition Key (Hash Key):****

> DynamoDB uses the partition key's value as input to an internal hash function. The output from the hash function determines the partition (physical storage internal to DynamoDB)

**2. Partition key and sort key:**

> Referred to as a composite primary key, this type of key is composed of two attributes. The first attribute is the partition key, and the second attribute is the sort key.
>
> DynamoDB uses the partition key value as input to an internal hash
> function. The output from the hash function determines the partition
> (physical storage internal to DynamoDB) in which the item will be
> stored. All items with the same partition key value are stored
> together, in sorted order by sort key value.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers in this question are correct, you cannot define a DynamoDB table without a hash key.  However, your question implies that you do not fully understand how DynamoDB works.

Think of DynamoDB as an infinitely large filing cabinet.  Inside this filing cabinet, you have an infinite number of folders.  Each folder may contain lots of files.

Because DynamoDB wants to make it super easy to find anything in the filing cabinet, each folder has a label that uniquely identifies the folder (e.g. Folder1, Folder2, ..., FolderN).  The files in each folder may also be sorted so you know exactly how to find a specific file inside each folder.

The hash key (also called partition key) in DynamoDB is like the label on the folder.  Without it, DynamoDB has no idea how to arrange or retreive your folder in the filing cabinet.

You always need to define a partition key so DynamoDB knows how to quickly store *and* fetch your data.  After all, that's why we use DynamoDB!

Comment: This is a great explanation. Are you implying that the sort key manages how the files are sorted in each folder? If yes, could you give a scenario where I could consider using a sort key to manage the file sorting?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  In this metaphor, the files within the folder are sorted by the sort key.  An example of a sort key could be a timestamp when the file was created so the files are stored and retrieved using a date range.  Another sort key could be the filename.  It's up to you to select a sort key that organizes your data in a way that supports your applications access patterns.